# How can I install the Play! framework using typesafe-stack?

Tags: linux, web-applications, playframework-2.0, typesafe-stack

I'd like to create a new project with the Play! framework. My system is Mint 12 64bit.  Since the newest version of Play! is already bundled with the typesafe-stack, I thought installation would be easy. I added the typesafe repo, then I apt-get updated and apt-get installed typesafe-stack with the command `g8 typesafehub/play-scala`.

I successfully created a new project in my home folder. Now the problems begin:

I don't know how to access Play! with this installation. After creating the project, I tried to convert it into an Eclipse project, it but there's no `play` command available in the terminal.

How can I get a "standard" Play! installation on Linux? What happens to the tools bundled in the typesafe stack - Where do they go?

Comment: I guess this belongs to Stackoverflow.com

Comment: See http://typesafe.com/resources/getting-started/tutorials/getting-started-with-play-scala.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use sbt where you would have used play.  They are one and the same in reality.

Comment: +1  I'll try this as soon as possible (I'm not on my machine right now) and accept the answer if it worked. Thanks

Comment: However, [this blog](http://blog.typesafe.com/introducing-play-20) says `play` in the first example.

Comment: right.  Looks like I should add an alias to `sbt` called `play`.  The `play` script is really just `sbt` with some templating editions.